# Delete from Oracle table rows older than 1 month

Tags: oracle, sysdate

In Oracle I have a table with a `DB_FLD_4` defined as `VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)` but actually holds DATE information with looks like this:

```
select DB_FLD_4 from DM_SUPDES_DISTRIB order by DB_FLD_4 desc;

4/9/2017
4/7/2017
4/6/2017
```

Kind of m/d/yyyy format.

I would like to create SP that would delete every day rows from the table older than 1 month.

My sysdate looks like this:

```
select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
24-APR-17 04.41:00
```

Please help to manipulate formats to make this possible.

Many thanks !!!

Comment: Have you tried anything to view this badly defined VARCHAR2 column as a date yet. Its good practise to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_date()` on your column, then trunc the sysdate to "round" to the day

```
delete
from MyTable
where to_date(MyColumn, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1)
```